# Using OTB-Mosaic plugin in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, mosaic, otb-applications

I want to use the **remicres/otb-mosaic plugin** (https://github.com/remicres/otb-mosaic) in QGIS.

Fig. 1 is the usage introduction given on the webpage.

[image: Fig. 1]

However I cannot find the function in QGIS after I copied the file "Mosaic.xml" into the QGIS installation path as instructed on the webpage.

How to find the function in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

If everything was installed and setup correctly, the function should become available in the Processing Toolbox. You can press Ctrl-Alt-t or use the "Processing" item in the menu bar to open it.

Comment: However,I didn't find the function in Processing Toolbox.